When in the history of Latin did the Proto-Indo-European geminates disappear? Why is the root *kakka reflected in Latin as "caco" rather than *cacco?
Like the title says. The PIE word for "shit" is *kakka, yet the Latin word is "caco", without the double 'c'. Why is that?

Proto-Indo-European did not have geminates. Where did you find *kakka?

@Cairnarvon https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/kakka-

Can you put the link inside the question instead of in a comment?

Proto-Indo-European didn't have geminates, in general. A small number of nursery words, such as *kak(k)a "feces" and *at(t)a "father", are sometimes reconstructed with especially long consonants, given their descendants in other languages. But these are special cases, and there aren't enough to make any generalizations about how they changed in the daughter languages—in other words, there's not a single other word with PIE *kk to compare against, so it's very possible that PIE *kk > Lat c is a perfectly "regular" development!
This is why some scholars, notably Kloekhorst, claim that the Proto-Indo-European "voiceless" stops were actually geminate (based on evidence from Anatolian). This is a rather fringe position compared to the traditional reconstruction and the glottalic theory, and in my opinion there's no solid reason to reconstruct these geminates before the Proto-Anatolian stage. But there's also no damning evidence against it, which we would have if PIE regularly contrasted single and geminate stops in other ways.

To be fair to Kloekhorst, he reconstructs geminates for Proto-Indo-Anatolian, not PIE proper; it's just that a lot of people don't distinguish between PIA and PIE.
